# ffmpeg mp3 to mp4 with image compatible with iphone

Tags: ffmpeg, iphone, mp3, mp4

I need to convert an mp3 to mp4 with image (1080x720) using ffmpeg from my OSX command line.

I already installed last version of ffmpeg (3.0.2), and tried the following command as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25382231/3649903)

```
./ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.jpg -i test.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest test.mp4
```

but the result mp4 file is not compatible with my iphone 5

Now this is what I am trying

```
./ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.png -i test.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 test.mp4
```

but the command takes a lot, never ends.
If I interrupt it, the output mp4 file is huge with a duration of about 45 min!
After 3:00 min I can see only the image without audio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to image dimensions, which should be even.

Try

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.png -i test.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=iw:-2 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -shortest test.mp4
```

Comment: What's the console readout?

Comment: please read my updated question

Comment: Updated command.